# Run out on last ball of a over in cricket match

Tags: cricket, cricket-world-cup

If 'A'  is playing on strike and 'B' is on non strike.its a 20 over match, and assume bowler balls always one side(bowler always balls from one side, there is no rotation on keeping and balling side after over completed.)

If 'A' runs for a single run on 6.5 over and B run out on striker end, who will on strike on 7.1 ball, 'A' or new batsman?

Answer (score 2):

> bowler always bowls from one side, there is no rotation

Note that this means that you are not playing in accordance with the Laws of Cricket. In particular, [Law 17.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/the-over) states:

> The ball shall be bowled from each end alternately in overs of 6 balls.

In theory, this means that the only answer to your question can only be "refer to the playing conditions for your competition", because the Laws cannot be used to answer a question when you are explicitly ignoring them. However, for the sake of practicality, I'll answer as for a match played in accordance with the Laws.

The important Law here is [18.12.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/scoring-runs):

> When a batsman is dismissed [run out], the not out batsman shall return to the wicket he/she has left but only if the batsmen had not already crossed at the instant of the incident causing the dismissal.

In the case you state where the non-striker is run out at the striker's end, the batsmen must have crossed<sup>1</sup> so the striker does *not* return to their original wicket and they are now at what was the non-striker's wicket. In a regular match, this would then mean they face the first ball of the next over when bowled from the other end.

<sup>1. If they had not crossed, the striker would have been run out because it would have been their ground in which the wicket was put down; refer to [Law 30.2](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws/batsman-out-of-his-her-ground) for details.</sup>